# Apache Hive Metastore - information_schema

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-metastore

I'm pretty new to Hive. I'm wondering whether it is possible to have an information_schema database with the Hive metastore data? For instance, databases that I create the Hive metastore and are returned when executing "show database", can these also be added to the information_schema.schemata table? I've found that the Hive metastore information is kept inside the Hive database, can I change this to be in information_schema?

Some posts, like the following, allude that an information_schema is possible, however, I cannot find any good resources on how to achieve this.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-16941

*** Update ***
We still have not yet decided on which version or vendor to go with. We are thinking of using the open source version, however, if a vendor offers this (and open source not), we will consider a vendor as this is an important issue for us.

Comment: Can you please specify your Hadoop Vendor, It's version, and Hive version?

Comment: @Pash0002 Updated post, we still have not decided on which version/ vendor. This schema_information issue is important and might driver us towards one version/ vendor instead of another.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1010 - Hive Version 3.0.0 and above stores the information_schema

Comment: @Pash0002 Thanks for this ! Tried running the schematool but it is failing for me, is there any clear instructions somewhere? Tried this against the default internal Derby database, does this work?

Comment: what are you trying with default internal Derby database?

Comment: Initially I had set Hive with the default internal Derby database, now I have Hive with external MySQL backend. I'm trying to run schematool to generate an information_schema database with the information of my metastore (e.g., if I have a table defined in metastore, this table will be in information_schema.tables?. Is this possible?

This post suggests that this is possible, however this command is failing for me: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-16942

Comment: Can you tell me what is your actual requirement? Do you want the metadata of hive tables? And about `information_schema.tables` in metastore will be MySQL's  `information_schema` not the Hive's.

Comment: We have a lot of pipelines which we're moving from one data platform (in which metadata is stored in/ queried from information_schema database) to another (one with a Hive metastore). We do not want to update the pipelines (due to time constraints), so trying to understand whether we can have a MySQL's information_schema with Hive's metastore data. information_schema.tables will be the MySQL's information_schema (and NOT Hive's hive table i.e., hive.TBLS).

Comment: Basically `information_schema` from MySQL and Hive both are different. And this  `information_schema` is supporting HIVE 3.0 and +. as per the [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-16942) you provided (**Fix Version**). You can check with your Hadoop vendor.

Answer (score 1):

I've developed this information_schema script for hive_metastore. Feel free to use-

```
cls = []
spark.sql("Drop view if exists allColumns")

for db in spark.sql("show databases").collect():
    for table in spark.catalog.listTables(f"{db.databaseName}"):
        try:
            for column in spark.catalog.listColumns(table.name, table.database):
                cls.append([table.database,table.name, column.name, column.dataType])
                print(table," table loaded successfully")
        except:
            print("Error Loading The Table ",table," in Information_Schema")
            
spark.createDataFrame(cls, schema = ['databaseName','tableName','columnName', 
'columnDataType']).createOrReplaceTempView("allColumns")

spark.sql("""create or replace table default.information_schema as select * from allColumns""")
```